# I don't understand the proof of following exercise from Do Carmo's differential geometry.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let me writh down what I'm trying to prove.

It comes from Do carmo's differential geometry sec 1.7.

Lets $\alpha(s), s \in [0, l]$ be a closed convex plane curve positively oriented.

The curve

$\beta(s)=\alpha(s)-rn(s)$, where $r$ is a positive constant and $n$ is the normal vector, is called a parallel curve to $\alpha$.

Show that

a. Length of $\beta$ = length of $\alpha$+$2 \pi r$

b. $A(\beta)=A(\alpha)+rl+\pi r^2$

c. $k_\beta (s) = \frac{k_\alpha (s)}{1+r k_\alpha (s)} $.

For (a)-(c), A($~~$) denotes the area bounded by the corresponding curve, and $k_\alpha , k_\beta$ sare the curvatures of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively.

And these are solutions to the above problems.[image]

[image]

I have no difficulty with part (a), but part (b) bugges me.

The only formula I have been learned from this book so far is

If $\alpha(s)=(x(s), y(s))$ is the parametrized simple closed curve,

then the area bounded by the curve is given
$\int xy'-yx' dt$, which can be written as a $\int \alpha \times \alpha' dt$.

And I think that the first approach of the second solution uses this method.

But I can't see how $\int \vert (\alpha - rn) \times (t - rn') \vert ds$ can be
the integral $\frac{1}{2} \int \vert \alpha \times \alpha' \vert ds + r \int \vert b \vert ds + r^2 \int k_\alpha ds$ which follows it.

and the first solution and the second approach of the second solution argue in the same reasoning, which is relied on $A(\beta)-A(\alpha)=\int_0^r L(\alpha)+2 \pi t dt$. Why this is so?

Thank you for reading this and answering in advance.